# Connecting Freeform Form with a specific page (so the client can do this)

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, structure

Here is the scenario ... I have freeform pro installed and working perfectly on a client's site.  The site uses the Structure module for creating pages, etc.  Currently I simply add the freeform form to a structure page by use of a conditional that checks the URL and if there is a match the form is rendered.

Client is asking for a way to select which page the form will go on so we can cut out the manual conditional check.  It seems to me there could be a way to do this but I'm coming up empty here.  Looking for some best practice type of advice here.

Answer (score 2):

I might be misunderstanding what you need, but whenever I've set this up I use Pixel & Tonic Switch in the channel entry to turn the form on or off. (That seems a bit simple so I'm guessing you are looking for something else!)

Answer (score 1):

This functionality exists in the FreeForm Pro version. Complete details here:

http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/channel_entry_fieldtype/

> Freeform allows you to call your forms directly into a channel entry.
>   Simply create a custom channel field (of the Freeform fieldtype), and
>   it will allow your admins to select Composer-based forms to be linked
>   directly to a the channel field. You can then have the form(s) display
>   on the front end alongside your channel entry using the
>   Channel:Entries tag.

The resulting field looks like this on the edit form:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use a custom field also.